# When do you use React-Router getChildRoutes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm confused about how and when you can use `getChildRoutes` because it's part of `PlainRoute`. How do you access `PlainRoute` in the first place? So instead of building `<Route>` components I can use `<PlainRoute>`s and then inside the component it was rendering it will have getChildRoutes? What does `partialNextState` refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Plain routes are ordinary JavaScript objects, and can be used in `<Router>` like so:

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  indexRoute: {
    component: Home,
  },
  childRoutes: [
    { path: 'page1', component: Page1 },
    {
      path: 'page2',
      component: SomeWrapper,
      childRoutes: [
        { path: 'subpage1', component: Subpage1 },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={ browserHistory } routes={ routes }/>, document.body);
```

That is, the `indexRoute` - if present - corresponds to adding an `<IndexRoute>` as a child of a `<Route>`, and `childRoutes` corresponds to adding child `<Route>`s. They both accept the same attributes as the corresponding JSX tags accept props.

Plain routes are useful for example for splitting your route definition up in multiple files. In a large app, it may be useful to decouple pages from their exact location in the route hierarchy, and build the route hierarchy up by importing `childRoutes` to immediate parent modules instead of having the entire route hierarchy hardcoded into the root module. It is also easy to build reusable navigation components like tab containers and breadcrumbs if you use plain routes, as the routes themselves can then be sent as props defining the links those components should include.

[`getChildRoutes`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.5/docs/API.md#getchildroutespartialnextstate-callback) and `getIndexRoute` are asynchronous variants of the `childRoutes` and `indexRoute` attributes, and allow for dynamic routing and code splitting. For example, you could for fun make `getChildRoutes` refer to itself recursively. I don't know what `partialNextState` is supposed to be, and I've never needed to use it.